# I need help understanding a couple lines of code

Tags: javascript, function, loops

can someone help me understand what is happening on this line:

```
chars[char] = (chars[char] || 0) + 1;
```

and on line:

```
.filter((char) => char[1] > 1).map((char) => char[0]);
```

```
/* FULL CODE */
const getRepeatedChars = (str) => {
  const chars = {};
  for (const char of str) {
    chars[char] = (chars[char] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return Object.entries(chars)
    .filter((char) => char[1] > 1)
    .map((char) => char[0]);
};

console.log(getRepeatedChars("aabbkdndiccoekdczufnrz"));
```

Comment: First line counts the occurrence of each character, second line returns all those characters that have a count larger than one. Set breakpoints, add debug logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chars[char] = (chars[char] || 0) + 1;
```

This adds `1` to the value of `chars[char]`. If there's no element in the object with key `char`, the value of `chars[char]` will be undefined. `undefined || 0` is `0`; adding `1` to this initializes the element to `1` the first time a particular character is encountered.

```
Object.entries(chars)
.filter((char) => char[1] > 1).map((char) => char[0]);
```

`Object.entries(chars)` returns an array whose elements are nested arrays of the form `[key, value]`, the keys and values of the `chars` object. The keys are the characters in the strings, the values are the repetition counts. So `char[1] > 1` tests if the character appeared more than once, and `filter()` returns an array where this is true. Then `.map()` returns `char[0]`, which is the character. So this returns the characters that appeared more than once.